# Ignoring standard and boost libraries while debugging with GDB

Tags: debugging, emacs, gdb

I haven't been able to google to find a definite answer to this question, so here goes.

Is it possible to ignore libraries while stepping through code using GDB? I was trying to debug a simple program but I was shown alot of peripheral and not interesting code while doing so - I'm really not interested in debugging archlinuxs implementation of the standard lib, or the boost library.

When stepping, I'd like GDB to simply run until it hits my own code - is such a filter possible? I'm using emacs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I prevent debugger from stepping into Boost or STL header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219223/can-i-prevent-debugger-from-stepping-into-boost-or-stl-header-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can notice that you will be stepping into an external library function just before issuing your `step` command. The simplest solution is to issue the `next` command instead of `step` when your marker is on an external library's function's call.

Comment: I haven't tested this, but doesn't this yield problems when writing composite statements such as vector.push_back(get_element(...));?

Comment: When you're on that line for the first time you'll need to `step` to get into `get_element`, you should issue `next` the second time.

Answer (score 0):

You can [strip](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_strip.htm) the debug symbols from the library that you don't intend to debug.

```
strip --strip-debug <lib_file.a>
```

rebuild your app, library files wont be shown in the debugger. So "step" to your lib call will be same as "next" in GDB.

OR

You can also choose not to have -g option when compiling lib files instead.

Comment: Should I thus strip the debug symbols from the standard library included with my distribution? Are there any reason not to?