# GDB reset configuration

Tags: c, gdb, valgrind

EDIT:
I tried to re-install `gdb` with `sudo apt-get autoremove gdb` and then `sudo apt-get install gdb`. Still doesn't resolve issue.

Original problem:

So recently, meaning roughly 3 hours ago, I installed `valgrind` to check for memory leaks and now everything I try to compile something and run GDB (terminal or in Eclipse), all `malloc`/`calloc` commands are also getting debugged step by step.

Testing File:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct tem{
    int i;
} name;

int main() {
    name *t;
    printf("EASD");
    t = malloc(sizeof(name));
    return 0;
}
```

Eclipse debugger Error (still shows variables in malloc and etc function):

```
Can't find a source file at "malloc.c" 
Locate the file or edit the source lookup path to include its location.
```

Compiled using :`cc -g -o asd a.c`
Debugged using :`gdb asd`

Terminal:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/userName/workspace/as/asd 

Breakpoint 2, main () at a.c:10
10      t = malloc(sizeof(name));
(gdb) step 18442
Single stepping until exit from function _fini,
which has no line number information.
Single stepping until exit from function __do_global_dtors_aux,
which has no line number information.
Single stepping until exit from function _fini,
which has no line number information.
EASD33  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/_exit.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) step
[Inferior 1 (process 6621) exited normally]
```

GDB without break point:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/userName/workspace/as/asd 
EASD[Inferior 1 (process 6631) exited normally]
```

My question is, how to I re-configure/reset GDB to skip over the standard library functions like it used to?

From another computer:

```
(gdb) run
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/userName/a.out a.out
warning: Could not load shared library symbols for linux-gate.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Breakpoint 1, main () at a.c:10
10      printf("EASD");
(gdb) step
11      t = malloc(sizeof(name));
(gdb) step
12      return 0;
(gdb) step
13  }
(gdb) step
0xb7e067c3 in __libc_start_main () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
```

Comment: Are you sure this is related to valgrind? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424211/ignoring-standard-and-boost-libraries-while-debugging-with-gdb.

Comment: @dbrank0 Similar, thanks for the link, but I was wondering is there a a way for having it work the way it used to. Literally I installed `valgrind`, next thing I know `GDB` starts working up. I've not used `valgrind` beforehand, but I don't see any problem from it (for now). I'm using it to check for memory leaks primarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I have to use `(gdb) skip file malloc.c` Thanks to GDB 7.4.

I would appreciate any alternative to restore what GDB used to do, so I dont have to manually add all the standard library source files manually (I tried `(gdb) skip file stdlib.h` just for those who wanted to know)