# Why does GDB try to list headers that don't exist?

Tags: c++, compilation, gdb

I am a noob learning c++ and using gdb for debugging.

In a Makefile, I compile my individual objs using:

```
g++ -Wall -g -O0 -c foo.cc
g++ -Wall -g -O0 -c bar.cc
...
```

then compile the entire executable using:

```
g++ -Wall -g -O0 foo.o bar.o -lncursesw
```

Then I use gdb to `step` through my code. It keeps stepping into the standard lib so I followed [this script recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219223/can-i-prevent-debugger-from-stepping-into-boost-or-stl-header-files#42721326) to skip over absolute file names that are prefixed with `/usr/include/c++/*`.

## Now my issue

gdb tries to list files that are not on my machine. If from inside gdb (after `start` command) I execute `info sources`, there are a bunch of files that are prefixed with `/build/gcc/*` which are not on my machine. **Why did GDB try to access them?**

When stepping through, I cannot skip over the files since gdb will tell me "No such file or directory"

```
std::basic_ifstream<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t> >::basic_ifstream (this=0x7fffffffc680, __in_chrg=<optimized out>,
__vtt_parm=<optimized out>) at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/fstream:518

/build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/fstream: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why did GDB source them?

When you execute `start` command, gdb starts running the program and stops at the beginning of `main`. Among other things, gdb loads all dynamically linked libraries that your program is linked with. One of them is libstdc++, standard C++ library. When it is loaded, gdb also loads it's debug info where files with `/build/gcc/*` prefix are present. If you are not going to debug libstdc++, there is no need to keep them on your machine.

Comment: A better answer is probably "don't step into standard library routines if you don't intend to look there".

Comment: @ks1322 `/build/gcc/*` are debug info files for libstdc++? If so, they are not on my machine and I do not want to debug the stdlib. So I am perplexed why gdb tries to source them and what is telling gdb they exist at `/build/gcc/*` directory.

Comment: @EmployedRussian exactly. I do not want to look in the standard library routines. I would like to skip over them. I managed to skip over `/usr/include/c++/*` but since `/build/gcc/*` directories dont exit on my machine, gdb warns me at each step that it cannot find the file. **I would like to know where gdb gets the idea to list `/build/gcc/*` headers**.

Comment: When you step into libstdc++ code, gdb tries to show it for you because it has debug info loaded for libstdc++. If you don't want this either do not step into libstdc++ code or skip files with `/build/gcc/*` prefix as you do it for `/usr/include/c++/*` or remove libstdc++ debug info with `strip`.

Comment: "I would like to know where gdb gets the idea to list /build/gcc/* headers" It gets this idea by looking at the debug symbols of the standard library, which was built on some computer from sources in `/build/gcc`. gcc does not and cannot have any idea whether this computer is the same computer it is now running on, and whether your intent is to debug the standard library or something else.