# How to debug your own code in C++ using vscode without running into the source code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb

when I debug my c++ code using vscode, it always step into vector source code

i want to only debug my coding,so,are there some command params in gdb ,or change some settings, in order to

don`t step into vector scource code

Comment: Old but may be useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219223/can-i-prevent-debugger-from-stepping-into-boost-or-stl-header-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219223/can-i-prevent-debugger-from-stepping-into-boost-or-stl-header-files) And if .gdbinit works this should help you set it in windows if that is your OS: [https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2758](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2758)

Comment: give this a try: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42985979/11107541 and tell us if it helps you